# How to make a transform animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script for my HTML page. I want to make the following in that script:

1. Show a preloading `#id` for some seconds and then fade out;
2. While the div is loading the main page under that div which is shown cause my `opacity` is to `0.7` I want to tranform the `nav-bar` up to browser windows so bassically hide it and in that position to tranform a new `nav-bar`.

I want that to take place while the preloading page is working not after!
And I want to show more contects in parraler with the `nav-bar` animation.

I created the script but I get lost in how to position my actions and I don't know if I made anything corrdctly. I make the fade out preloader.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#fade").css({opacity: 0.7})
    $("#fade").delay(4000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('#nav-before').transition({ y: '40px' }); //now I want to hide the nav
        //and show the new with id="nav-after"
            //and in parraller with the above to be able to load more contects
        $("#fade").remove(); //when evrything finished kill the div
    });

});
```

Comment: create fiddle so that it is easy to identify the problem.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I use Bootstrapt with costum HTML and CSS styles. I really want to do it but it'll take some time and now I'm in the middle of project ( some days now) Time is gold for me now

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#fade" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.0
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

You can play with ***animate***. Here is the reference: [jquery.com/animate/](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)